# I am unable to see my component's file names and line numbers whenever I log to the console, even though I can see the sourceMap info there

Tags: angular, webpack

I am running an application using Angular 11, and with the updated source map configuration as suggested by the Angular team. However, I've not been able to see any information with regards to the log messages as to where they are being generated from i.e. which file and line number. I believe this has something to do with source maps, however they are configured as they should be (referring to the official documentation here).

To clarify, I used to be able to see the required information, but somewhere after the upgrade it has pretty much vanished. All I see is `build.umd.js:...` after the log messages.